# What is this plant with small red fruits?

Tags: identification, edible

And more to the point, are the fruits edible?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one isn't [deadly nightshade (Atropa belladonna)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atropa_belladonna) but [woody nightshade, (Solanum dulcamara)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanum_dulcamara); as such, its berries are toxic and therefore inedible. It tends to appear on its own, so look out for more plants next year.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a Nightshade (solanum) , also known as Deadly Nightshade : strong hint that it is not eatable.